# One to one relation not setting primary key

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I have a schema where Table1 had a primary auto increment identity key and Table2 has a primary key with a FK constraint that it equals the Table1 primary key.

Schema is:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
     [Key] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
     [Key] ASC
 )

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
     [Key] [bigint] NOT NULL,
     [Value] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
     [Key] ASC
 )

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_Table1] FOREIGN KEY([Key])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([Key])
```

Code is:

```
void Main()
{
    var table1 = new Table1 
    {
        Value = "table1",

        Table2 = new Table2
        {
            Value = "table2",
        }
    };

    Table1.InsertOnSubmit(table1);

    SubmitChanges();
}
```

Then do an insert and save it complains that the Table2 can't insert duplicate foreign key.

I'm guessing that it's not setting the primary key value in Table2 with the return from the Table1 insert and I can't figure out how to do this without making it two separate calls.

Comment: try `new Table2{}` instead `Table2 = new Table2{}`

Comment: did you insert multiple `Table1` at the same scope ?

Comment: I have verified that this works from Visual Studio so I've reported it as a bug to LinqPad and will await a response from that.